the underlying mechanics of dind(docker in docker)
I was under the impression that DinD is just a trick to use host docker daemon, however I recently read it's not true, that it's really a nested containerization.
I'm interested in the mechanics of it, how Linux manages the hierarchy in terms of namespaces, cgroups volumes and network. Also which syscalls involved.
Thanks in advance :)

With the --privileged option, the container can do most of the things the host system can do. See https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/ for the official explanation of what the first container needs to have

Namespaces and cgroups are hierarchical by nature.
Namespaces: Each namespace is either the root namespaces of its type or has a parent namespace. A process can create a new namespace that will be a child of the current namespaces by using the CLONE_NEW* flags of the clone syscall or by using the unshare syscall. You can play with the unshare syscall with the unshare program which is quite straight-forward.
cgroups: Even without creating a new cgroup namespace, cgroup itself is hierarchical in the sense that every cgroup is either the root cgroup or has a parent cgroup. All the restrictions of the parent cgroup are applied to the child cgroup. All processes under a child cgroup belong to the parent cgroup as well.
Nested volumes are possible because the filesystem is hierarchical and one can mount a filesystem in a directory of another filesystem. The host filesystem is hidden from the guest by using a new mount namespace. This can be nested because namespaces can be nested.
Network is handled by the net namespace, which again, can be nested.
And many of these things require capabilities in the root namespace, which can be achieved by running the container with the --privileged flag
